# Using coqide, the command `Require Import BigN` worked using coq 8.6 but not in coq 8.7

Tags: coq, opam

I used OPAM to install bignum

```
$ opam upgrade bignum
Already up-to-date.
```

With coq 8.6 the code `Require Import BigN.` imported the library but
with coq 8.7 I get an error.
So I isolate this line of code in a file bignum_problem.v. Then running
`coqc bignum_problem` produces the response

> File "./bignum_problem.v", line 1, characters 15-19:
>
> Error: Unable to locate library `BigN`.

The documentation for Coq modules suggests that I need a file BigN.vo but no such file appears in the .opam directory. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `bignum` refers to an OCaml library; you might want to install `coq-bignums` instead.  I just installed that library on my machine and was able to require `BigN` with the command

```
From Bignums Require Import BigN.
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I found `http://coq.io/opam/coq-bignums.8.7.0.html` and tried their command `opam install coq-bignums.8.7.0` but still get an error `[ERROR] No package named coq-bignums found.`

Comment: @BarryJay I was able to install it via `opam install coq-bignums.8.7.0`. You probably need to execute `opam update` before trying to install the library.

Comment: You also need the coq-specific repo: `opam repo add coq-released https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released`

Comment: All working now. I needed all three answers to get there! Thanks Arthur, Anton and gallais.